# Форматы страниц и индексация

Tags: индексация, html, php

Можно ли на сайте использовать несколько страниц с разными форматами например .html и .php? И не скажется ли это на поисковой индексации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно. Не скажется. Но лучше использовать ЧПУ.